# Searching for strings with BeuatifulSoup

Tags: regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I expected that the following code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
sopa = BeautifulSoup('<ol><li>this is a string</li></ol>')
sopa.find_all(string=re.compile("a"))
```

would return `[u'this is a string']` but it returns `[]`. Why?

The BeautifulSoup 4 documentation gives this example:

```
soup.find_all(string=re.compile("Dormouse"))
```

which, when acting on a soup of an Alice in Wonderland excerpt, is supposed to return

```
[u"The Dormouse's story", u"The Dormouse's story"]
```

The documentation also says that bs4 uses `re.match()` (which matches the beginning of a string) but other places (as well as this example from the official docs) indicate `re.search()`, and changing the regex `"a"` to `"this"` has no effect on the result in any case.

Comment: Solved. version <4.4 the argument was `text`

Answer (score 0):

Well it can also work if you print last line, I've tried, its working

```
print(sopa.find_all(string=re.compile("a")))
```

You can also get text by

```
print(sopa.getText())
```

and 3rd method

```
print(sopa.get_text())
```